# Open standard Business Process Execution Language

Tags: open-source, bpel

Can any one tell me what are the available open standard Business Process Execution Language.

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly got the question... The most recent version of the BPEL spec can be found here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/wsbpel-v2.0.html. There are open source BPEL engines such as Apache ODE (http://ode.apache.org) available. Let me know if this answers your question or try to make it more precise.